Convenient method to get the size of a shared memory on Linux
I have two processes on Linux, which are sharing a block of memory created by shm_open + ftruncate + mmap.
After the producer created the shm, the consumer need to known the size of the shm when it's plugging the shm.
These two process are NOT in parent/child relation, so I can NOT naturally carry the size from one into another by means of fork.
As to any RPC methods, I think they are too heavy, while I merely need to get the size of a shm.
Is there a simple/convenient method to do this?

You can share fixed-size memory block first with buffer size field. For producer/consumer you'll probably need shared synchronization primitives, you can place them to the same fixed-size block as well.

I think what you are looking for is something like this (in the consumer process) to get the size of the shared memory area:
int areaID = [... value returned by shm_open() or shmget() ...]

struct shmid_ds buf;
if (shmctl(areaID, IPC_STAT, &buf) != -1)
{
   const size_t areaSizeBytes = buf.shm_segsz;
   [...]
}
else perror("shmctl(IPC_STAT)");


Thanks for your hint!  But shmctl is a SystemV API, not related with shm_open, maybe it works.

Did you actually test this with shm_open?  It does not work for me; the value of shm_segsz does not agree with the size originally passed to ftruncate.

No, my code uses shmget() instead of shm_open().

You can call fstat on the file descriptor returned by shm_open, and the st_size field will contain the size of the object as set by ftruncate.
